# Use current password in arcgis.gis

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, arcgis-portal, authentication, arcgis-python-api

I'm currently signed into my portal through ArcGIS Pro. When I want to use a python notebook to update my portal, I use:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
my_gis = GIS(
             url='https://<my Org's URL>', 
             cert_file = <path to cert>, 
             password = <my password>, 
             username='ANY'
             )
```

Since I'm already signed into my Portal in ArcGIS Pro, is there a way that I can automatically pass it my password?

It doesn't seem to need a username; I just pass in 'ANY'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a specific [authentication scheme just for ArcGIS Pro](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/working-with-different-authentication-schemes/#Connecting-through-ArcGIS-Pro)

```
print("\n\nActive Portal in ArcGIS Pro")  
gis = GIS("pro")
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me; it might not like that I have a certificate.

Comment: @SwiftestKoala I'd suggest adding more information to your question, like the exact error you're getting, which version of the Python API. You said you're using a Notebook in the question, in another comment you mention wanting to do this in a toolbox. Have you tried other authentication types from the link I posted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SignInToPortal](https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/signintoportal.htm) function to sign in to your ArcGIS Pro portal :

```
import arcpy

arcpy.SignInToPortal(arcpy.GetActivePortalURL(), 'username', 'password')
```

You may also need to look at [Connect to the GIS in Python scripts without embedded passwords or login prompts](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-blog/connect-to-the-gis-in-python-scripts-without/ba-p/889867) in the Esri community.

Comment: The OP is using the ArcGIS Python API. You still need to hydrate the GIS object with a connection. Logging into Portal via the arcpy tool will not do that.

Comment: This. I want to make a toolbox that will allow a user to update portal items. The goal is that the username and password won't need to be hardcoded anywhere; all the user has to do is sign in.